# Is it a personal care or a Company care to correct the list of Authors of a Patent owned by the Company?

Tags: copyright, patents, authorship

My name was missed in several patents issued by a Company with whom I was in the past. I contacted a very experienced Attorney in Employer-Employee Relations for an advice. His belief was that I cannot do anything if the Company does not want to add my name as an Author of a patent owned by The Company. However, this is a matter of Authorship but not a matter of Ownership. In Authorship it is only the Person (the Author) who matter. A Company may own the Patent but they do not own the persons names.

I gave the Attorney the following example: I own a Mercedes car and in my garage I replaced all the car signs of Mercedes with those of GM. I can do that because I own the car, but I cannot drive such a car on the street - It is illegal to change the Authorship (in that case Mercedes). He said "Very interesting example - I have not thought about such situation" but he remained firm on the belief that I cannot do anything to protect my name as an Author if the patent is owned by a Company, and the Company does not want to include my name regardless that the key idea of the patent is mine.

In other words, I think it is illegal to ignore an Author of a patent, and it is a personal care of the missing Author in the list this to be corrected. It is not a Company care. I believe that a Person do not need an agreement by the Company to file a claim for Patent Authorship and support his claim with enough evidences.

Comment: Your example would be more appropriate if you filed the patent yourself and then sold the patent to the company and they subsequently removed your name from the patent as the author.  You are not going to get your name added to the patent.  You might be able to get the patent invalidated if you can show that you did the work before the patent was applied for by claiming prior art.

Comment: Please state your jurisdiction.

Comment: The car example doesn't seem either correct or relevant.  Changing the insignia on your car from Mercedes to GM might violate GM's trademark, but I don't think Mercedes would have any claim against you.  As far as I know, you could legally remove all the Mercedes insignia, or replace them with a hammer and sickle, or a logo of your own design. It's your car.  Mercedes lost the right to control what insignia are on it when they sold it to you.  Anyway, this has nothing at all to do with patents.

Comment: And I know of no law that would forbid you from driving the car with the modified insignia.  You seem to think there's a fundamental right of "author credit" in all areas of law, but I don't think there is.

Comment: @NateEldredge - It is illegal in most if not all states to register or licence a vehicle that displays fraudulent manufacturer information.  The gm is a bad example but you could remove the AMC information form an old Pacer and put a Porsche logo on it.  Yeah you get in trouble for that.  Thats why if you ever see a kit car they do not have the trademark logo's on them.

Comment: @Chad: Interesting.  Citation?

Comment: [Here is the California](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=veh&group=11001-12000&file=11700-11740) one.    Its similar in all states it seems based on the google results

Comment: @Chad: That's 30,000 words.  Can you point out the specific subsection?  I tried searching the page for "logo", "marking", "insignia" but no matches.

Comment: I have no jurisdiction power at all. I am an ordinary inventor from whom a Company  made billions of dollars and at the same time omit my name form patents (base on my original ideas) issued by the same Company after my contract was terminated with "Do not Meet Expectation" performance assessment :).

Comment: @Chezare: "Jurisdiction" means the body of laws that you are subject to.  Usually this is defined by the country where you live.  So I'm asking, in order to determine what the law requires, we need to know which set of laws to look at.  The US? France? Paraguay?  They may all give different answers to your question.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge
I live in the US. The Company under my discussion  is located out of the USA but it is owned by US Corporation.

Comment: @Chad  It looks like if a High Quality Product (HQP)  is presented publicly as manufactured by a Manufacturer of Low Quality Products this does not hurt the HQP Manufacturer (?). However, it does because it creates public impression that the LQP Manufacture can offer same HQP as the HQP Manufacturer.

Comment: related questions (with answers that seem to confirm the answer given below) on patents.se: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/how-do-patents-on-product-inventions-designs-work-if-inventions-are-signed-off-t http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/12056/how-does-the-german-arbeitnehmererfinderrecht-protect-my-rights-when-my-employer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to speak with a patent attorney, not a labor attorney. Some of the facts you are presenting are entirely wrong.

Patents have inventors, copyrights have authors. Inventorship has strict rules.

Inventorship cannot be denied without consequence in almost any jurisdiction, but you'll need to get local legal advice.  In the US, "A patent is invalid unless it lists the first and true inventor or inventors of the claimed invention." (See Stark v. Advanced Magnetics, 119 F.3d 1551, 1553, 1556 (Fed. Cir. 1997); 35 U.S.C. § 102(f) (“A person shall be entitled to a
patent unless . . . he did not himself invent the subject matter sought to be patented). See also 35 U.S.C. §§ 111, 115-16, 256.)

*Assignment*--the "ownership" of the patent--is different. It's very common to have you sign an agreement as a condition of your employment that you grant full assignment to your company for any patentable material created under their employ. If you did not, it is possible that the company would need to give you consideration for the right to assignment, e.g., they would have to pay you something to own the patent. If you are no longer there, that "something" can be substantial, because the patent is invalid without it, and they have little leverage over you.

Bring all written records, emails, etc. to a licensed attorney who specializes in patent litigation.

Comment: Thank you Jim. Your answer is of great value to my case (thump up !)
@ihtkwot

Comment: I am taking the chance to share my personal opinion with those who has jurisdictional  power that the Authors of a patent are not awarded if the Company owns the patent/invention. Indeed the law allows Employees to negotiate the conditions for patent/invention that originate from them  however who is going to hire us even we ask for 0.01% of a patent which can bring millions in profit?-I think there should be a law that Authors of a patent  must get %( form -to) of the profit due to the patent realization in the market by the Company owning the patent, but not a subject of a special agreement.

Comment: Inventors do not come any longer to the USA because they do not see stimulus as they did in the past. 

This, I believe is a good example: http://bt-isotopes.com/

Comment: @Chezare That is more complicated than one might expect--cross-licensing deals and bulk negotiations between large companies make it hard to determine the true value, and those figures are often not disclosed for good reason. You also don't normally see a percentage of profits for physical or software products, where the value is much more straightforward. And what about defensive patents that don't generate revenue, but save incalculable sums? Fact is, most patents in a large company don't generate revenue. A law here would create a mess.

Comment: Jim, I fully agree that is VERY complicated but somehow the Law should guarantee stimulus for the Inventors. Without stimulus,  the inventors will not going to invent anything while being employed.  Finding an investor and setting a privately owned company within a reasonable time frame is not at all an easy move.

Finally we end in a situation when the Country is not using the brain of its people. However, the progress today is driven by Invention - not by labor.Leaving the matter on Company's decision won't change anything - it has to be postulated by patent Law to become a drive.

Comment: @Chezare : Your bt-isotopes.com example looks like snake oil of the highest order, by the way. The invention is patented outside the US because it's nonsense, not because of unfavorable IP laws

Comment: @Chezare Many companies do offer renumeration for filed and/or granted patents. The large and growing rate of patent fillings seems to say that there isn't a motivation problem.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill It is too early to say whether or not the Chemical Transmutation is a nonsense or not. By proclaiming any invention which is not patented in the US as nonsense is not a stimulus for  Inventors to immigrate to the USA..

Comment: @jimm101 jim, I disagree. I have working experience in four countries on three continents and that has been always an issue. You are right that the Authors have to grand the right to the Company for issuing the patent in a written consent for each patent separately (if not done in a special agreement)  but if they did not agree most likely  their contract will be terminated or their name will be omitted. My final point is that the Inventor's compensation could be guarantee by the Law. It is not so complicated for the Lawmakers to cover all possible scenarios, I believe.

Comment: @Jimm101, Jim, I came back to this this discussion again with a clear question: To whom I should bring the issue that a Company has ignored my name as an Inventor of an idea used in the Company patents, issued after the company has  "accepted my resignation"? - Should that be the Law Firm mentioned in the Correspondence address of the patent, or I should contact the US Patent Bureau, or I should hire a third party Pattern Attorney to deal with this matter if it is a complicated for parson like me who has a little knowledge of the patent law?

Comment: May I ask someone with reputation of 150 or above to add a tag invention (or inventors). I am surprised that there is no such tag in the Law section ( that is why I started using authorship instead).

Comment: @Chezare I don't know. The law firm representing the company represents the company, so that's not likely to be fruitful. Your own law firm may be necessary to have your word taken seriously. However, you have no upside--if the company left your name off, they likely invalidated the patent, and your attorney can't negotiate a threat to expose them because he will have an obligation to report this to the USPTO. It's not ethical. If they license the patent to a competitor, the competitor may have some interest in pursuing things and compensating you for it. There's no easy win here for you.

Comment: @jimm101 Hi Jim, Thank you very much, I highly appreciate your very professional answers on my questions.